# Selecting rows in one column on the basis of a selected range

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a macro for formatting cells on the basis of a range selected in another column. Here I want to select the rows in column B on the basis of selected range in column A, i.e.,
I want to select the portion in column B for which column A has value. But when I run this it gives an error "Type Mismatch"

I used this code for the purpose:

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim LR As Long
Dim n As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
n = Range("A1:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Range("B1:B" & n).Select
End Sub
```

I am new in VBA. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the line

```
n = Range("A1:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

You have declared `n` as a long, but `SpecialCells` returns a Range.
I am not sure how to fix this, as I can't tell what you are trying to do.  But my first attempt would be

```
dim Rng as Range
Set Rng = Range("A1:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

This should fix your error.